# Ajax Call To Spring Service

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make a simple ajax call to a spring REST service I have setup.

My controller is defined as follows:

```
@Controller
public class SongPlayerController {
    ....
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/ajax", "/ajax/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String ajax() {
        return "New Song URL";
    }
}
```

And then I have a simple html page with an ajax request:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "http://localhost:8080/song-player/ajax",
            data : "text",
            success : function(response) {
                $('#ajax').val(response);
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
    }

    function getAjax() {
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/song-player/ajax', function(data) {
            alert('Ajax data' + data);
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadAjax()">Ajax Call</button>
    <div id="ajax">This will be an ajax call.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But, neither using the `$.ajax` or `$.getJSON` are returning anything. When using the ajax call, I'm getting the error "Error: [object Object]".

However, I know that my controller is setup properly because I can hit my service and get a response by using the [RESTClient Firefox add-on](http://restclient.net/) so I assume the problem is with how I'm handling the jQuery calls but this is my first attempt at using jQuery so I don't know what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what others have pointed out about malfomred json, it seems that my problem stemmed from trying to hit my service needed to be called with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

I ended up modifying the controller to follow [this blog post](http://www.fouzi.com/blog/?p=303) for wrapping my responses with a callback parameter.

I also changed up my ajax call to expecte JSONP:

```
function loadAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "http://localhost:8080/song-player/ajax.json",
            async : false,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success : function(response) {
                            $('#ajax').text(response.streamUrl);
                alert('Success: ' + response);
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.streamUrl);
        });
    }
```

Thanks for all of the help.

Answer (score 2):

The string literal `"New Song URL"` is not valid JSON.  Try returning this:

```
@Controller
public class SongPlayerController {
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/ajax", "/ajax/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String ajax() {
        return "{\"url\":\"New Song URL\"}";
    }
}
```

Then access this value as follows:

```
function getAjax() {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/song-player/ajax', function(data) {
        alert('Ajax data' + data.url);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)'s `stringify()` function as follows:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/song-player/ajax', function(data) {
    alert('Ajax data' + JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Comment: too bad `data` is not valid json in this case

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#ajax').val(response);
```

wont work. this is a div. use

```
$('#ajax').text(response);
```

thats why `loadAjax` doesnt work. `getAjax` doesnt work because as others pointed out, your response is not valid json, so getJSON will not work.